# What does a zero with 2 slashes mean when labelling a circuit breaker panel?

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel

An electrician added a new circuit to our panel today.  It was simple, a 20A dedicated circuit to power a treadmill.  He labelled the new breaker on the door of the panel:

[image]

What does the circle with two slashes indicate?  I see it on a few other circuits as well.

Comment: Specifically, this is the symbol commonly used on architectural drawings to denote a duplex outlet (two sockets).  You may also see similar symbols for single-socket outlets (circle with one vertical line) or for quad outlets (circle with two vertical and two horizontal lines, like a # symbol). The symbols are more useful for the single/quad outlet cases since those are less common and the extra information can make it easier to locate the outlet in question.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It means the circuit terminates in an outlet. That outlet used for the treadmill

Comment: And ... that notation will confuse another person who owns the house or works on the panel, who has no idea where the treadmill was or which outlet it was plugged into. It's much better to identify an outlet by room ("SW 20x30", "Kitchen" etc.) and wall ("N").

Comment: I see that, @Wastrel.  But considering how heavy the thing is I think it will be there for some time to come :)

Comment: @Wastrel that's how I ended up with breakers at my last house named 'freezer', 'computer room', and 'office'. Finally had to give up and get one of those breaker locators.

Comment: Look on the bright side, at least it doesn't say "new outlet" (because it stays "new" forever of course).

Comment: @ChrisParker exactly - the next outlet to be installed is "new new outlet" obviously.

Comment: It's actually against code to describe it like "computer room". NEC 408.4(A) "No circuit shall be described in a manner that depends on transient conditions of occupancy."

Comment: @Wastrel I don't think I have ever owned a house where the breaker circuits were labelled in an understandable manner.  One of the first things I always wind up doing when buying a new house is to create a schematic mapping every last outlet, switch, light, etc. to which breaker controls it.  It makes a nice parting gift when selling as well...

Answer (score 11):

**In blueprints** it marks an outlet.  I suppose on a panel it marks that there is an outlet on the circuit?  Not too useful.

What's important is the 1st-grade penmanship.  I believe that's mandatory on panels.

Comment: I'll take credit for the penmanship.   I drew it here with a mouse

Comment: @nuggethead Yeah, the computer-precise circle might've been a giveaway this wasn't done entirely by hand...

Comment: Also, in fairness, many times labels are being written directly on the panel, which isn't flat.

Comment: Do you ever have a moment where you wish you took a picture of every panel door in every place you lived in your life?   Ok probably not ... but I'm having that now.  :)

Comment: There's always a label maker, and for installs older than 3 decades, Dymo tape. It's an issue of extra effort.

Comment: @user71659   There is no "always" for any item, no matter how important it is.